# parsing in python/selenium loading the site

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I have a big problem. I'm starting to learn parsing in python/selenium, and decided to start with site parsing [https://yandex.ru/q/search/?text=любовь](https://yandex.ru/q/search/?text=%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8C) but there the wanderer is loaded from the bottom. How do I make the script collect all the links when loading the site? I only get 19 necessary links

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://yandex.ru/q/search/?text=любовь')
stats = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_1_SSPNHbSD']//a")
print('URLS ', len(stats))
for i in stats:
    url = i.get_attribute('href')
    print(url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep Scrolling down. You can change the number of `scrolls` as per your need. This will give `188` Urls.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:.../cd79/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://yandex.ru/q/search/?text=любовь')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(15)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
scrolls = 4
while True:
    scrolls -= 1
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(3)
    if scrolls < 0:
        break
stats = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_1_SSPNHbSD']//a")
print('URLS ', len(stats))
for i in stats:
    url = i.get_attribute('href')
    print(url)
```